# How do I create a boolean variable linked to the printed output?

Tags: python, boolean, ping

I would like to create logic depending on the result of this command. I can see a '1' or '0' printed on my terminal but I'm not sure how to create a boolean variable from this result.

> ```
> subprocess.call("ping 192.168.1.127 -c 1 | grep 'received' | awk -F',' '{ print $2}' | awk '{ print ""$1}'", shell=True)
>
> res2 = subprocess.call("ping 192.168.1.127 -c 1 | grep 'received' | awk -F',' '{ print $2}' | awk '{ print ""$1}'", shell=True)
>
> print("res2 is " + str(res2))
> ```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Also, do note that there is a Python library for ICMP, so you don't necessarily need to use the shell commands for ping: https://pypi.org/project/icmplib/.

Answer (score 0):

The subprocess.call function in Python runs a command in the shell and returns the exit status of the command as an integer. In this case, the command you are running is a pipeline of shell commands that pings a specific IP address, filters the output to only include the line with the word "received", and then extracts and prints the number of received packets.

The exit status of the subprocess.call function will be 0 if the command ran successfully, and a non-zero value if there was an error.

To create a boolean variable based on the result of the subprocess.call function, you can simply use a conditional statement. For example:

```
import subprocess

# Run the command and store the result in a variable
result = subprocess.call("ping 192.168.1.127 -c 1 | grep 'received' | awk -F',' '{ print $2}' | awk '{ print ""$1}'", shell=True)

# Check the result and create a boolean variable
if result == 0:
    received = True
else:
    received = False

# Print the boolean variable
print("received is " + str(received))
```